# Capturing screenshot of selection group input drop-down using Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How can I capture a **screenshot** of a **selection group input drop-down** using **Puppeteer**? I've verified that I'm able to open the drop-down (with multiple items) but when I try to capture a screenshot, the drop-down is not captured

Answer (score 1):

**They are not rendered by the browser it can't be caught inside the screenshot.**

---

Lets explain a problem with an example:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-example-kiowr

URL: https://kiowr.csb.app

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // "puppeteer": "2.0.0"

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://kiowr.csb.app");
  await page.click('[data-test="ice-cream"]');
  await page.screenshot({
    path: "ice-cream.png",
    omitBackground: true
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Expanded selects are rendered by the OS and they are different - (macOS vs Windows):

[image: macOS] 
[image: Windows]

**As they are not rendered by the browser it can't be caught inside the screenshot.**